# Row-wise operation by group over time R

Tags: r, dplyr

**Problem:**
I am trying to create variable *x2* which is equal to 1, for all rows within each *ID* group where over *time* *x1* switches from 1 to 0. 
Additionally, after the switch, every consecutive 0 in the run, *x2* is set to 1.

I tried to figure out how to do this using `library(dplyr)`, but could not figure out how to look at previous records within the group.

**Input Data:**

```
ID<-c("1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","4","4","5","5","5")
time<-c("1","2","3","4","5","1","2","3","4","1","2","3","1","2","1","2","3")
x1<-c("0","1","1","1","1","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","1","1","1","0","1")
df<-data.frame(ID,time,x1)
```

**Required Output:**

```
ID time x1 x2
1    1  0  0
1    2  1  0
1    3  1  0
1    4  1  0
1    5  1  0
2    1  0  0
2    2  0  0
2    3  0  0
2    4  0  0
3    1  1  0
3    2  0  1
3    3  0  1
4    1  1  0
4    2  1  0
5    1  1  0
5    2  0  1
5    3  1  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to have the 'x1' as `numeric` column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,  x2 := (cumsum(x1) < 2)*cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(x1) < 0)), ID]
df
#    ID time x1 x2
# 1:  1    1  0  0
# 2:  1    2  1  0
# 3:  1    3  1  0
# 4:  1    4  1  0
# 5:  1    5  1  0
# 6:  2    1  0  0
# 7:  2    2  0  0
# 8:  2    3  0  0
# 9:  2    4  0  0
#10:  3    1  1  0
#11:  3    2  0  1
#12:  3    3  0  1
#13:  4    1  1  0
#14:  4    2  1  0
#15:  5    1  1  0
#16:  5    2  0  1
#17:  5    3  1  0
```

#### data

```
ID<-c("1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","4","4","5","5","5")
time<-c("1","2","3","4","5","1","2","3","4","1","2","3","1","2","1","2","3")
x1<- as.integer(c("0","1","1","1","1","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","1","1","1","0","1"))
df<-data.frame(ID,time,x1)
```

Comment: @BEMR Could you please update your post as it is not clear from the comment

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `dplyr` answer, you can use @akrun's code in `mutate` after grouping by ID

```
library(dplyr)

ID<-c("1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","4","4","5","5","5")
time<-c("1","2","3","4","5","1","2","3","4","1","2","3","1","2","1","2","3")
x1<- as.integer(c("0","1","1","1","1","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","1","1","1","0","1"))
df<-data.frame(ID,time,x1)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(x2 = (cumsum(x1) < 2)*cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(x1) < 0)))

df
# ID   time    x1    x2
# 1      1     0     0
# 1      2     1     0
# 1      3     1     0
# 1      4     1     0
# 1      5     1     0
# 2      1     0     0
# 2      2     0     0
# 2      3     0     0
# 2      4     0     0
# 3      1     1     0
# 3      2     0     1
# 3      3     0     1
# 4      1     1     0
# 4      2     1     0
# 5      1     1     0
# 5      2     0     1
# 5      3     1     0
```